# In wordpress video attachment mkv format not playing .How to play them?

Tags: wordpress, mkv

I have added video as attachment , its automatically playing mp4 videos but not others as mkv. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It's playing MP4 because the browsers support natively MP4 files; for different video format the best way is to decode your MKV videos in MP4 format.

For other info:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-embed-mkv-videos/

For more info about the media supported natively by the browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility